# Local martingale with increasing process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Here is a problem in stochastic calculus:

If $M_t$ is a continuous process and $A$ an increasing process, then $M$ is a local martingale with increasing process $A$ if and only if, for every $f\in C^2$,
$f(M_t)-f(M_0)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(M_s)dA_s$ is a local martingale.

I am stuck in understanding the phrase "$M$ is a local martingale with increasing process $A$". Does it mean here $A$ should serve as a continuous sequence of stopping times to reduce $M$, or something else?

Comment: can you also include the textbook you are referring to so that I can check for sure that they refer to quadratic variation?

Comment: Hi Thomas, you are correct. This refers to the quadratic variation.

Answer (score 2):

They simply refer to the quadratic variation i.e. $A_{s}:=\langle M\rangle_s$. Just for completeness, I will include the proof for that question.

If we assume that $M$ is local martingale with quadratic variation $A$, then indeed by [generalized Itô's formula](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/) we get

$$ f(M_t) =  \int_0^t f'(M_s) dM_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(M_s) d\langle M \rangle_s + f(M_0) $$

and so

$$ f(M_t) -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(M_s) dA_s -f(M_0)=  \int_0^t f'(M_s) dM_s  $$

is indeed a local martingale.

Conversely, if the LHS is a local martingale, then we can just take $f(x)=x$.